# Adding bootstrap ison in a form shifts alignment off center

Tags: css

I'm trying to add a reveal password button to a form. Everything lines up nicely until I add the bootstrap icon.

As I adjust the images `margin-left` property to pull it into the text box, the text box shifts right seemingly half as much.

I believe it has something to do with the input width property as the issue goes away if the text box is full width. I can't figure out the fix.

```js
const togglePassword = document.querySelector("#togglePassword");
const password = document.querySelector("#password");
togglePassword.addEventListener("click", function() {
  const type =
    password.getAttribute("type") === "password" ? "text" : "password";
  password.setAttribute("type", type);
  this.classList.toggle("bi-eye");
});
```

```css
html {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

p {
  font-size: 1.4rem;
}

input[type="text"],
input[type="number"],
input[type="password"],
select {
  width: 50%;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  margin: 18px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

form i {
  margin-left: -60px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.content {
  padding: 1%;
}

.card-grid {
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 2rem;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(300px, 1fr));
}

.card {
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 12px 1px rgba(140, 140, 140, 0.5);
}

.card-title {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #034078;
}

input[type="submit"],
input[type="reset"],
select {
  border: none;
  color: #fefcfb;
  background-color: #034078;
  padding: 15px 15px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  width: 100px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
}

label {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
}

.value {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  color: #1282a2;
}

.state {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  color: #1282a2;
}

input[type="submit"]:hover,
input[type="reset"]:hover,
select {
  background-color: #1282a2;
}

button {
  border: none;
  color: #fefcfb;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  width: 100px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
}

.button-on {
  background-color: #034078;
}

.button-on:hover {
  background-color: #1282a2;
}

.button-off {
  background-color: #858585;
}

.button-off:hover {
  background-color: #252524;
}

.fcc-btn {
  border: none;
  color: #fefcfb;
  background-color: #034078;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  width: 100px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
}

.fcc-btn-on {
  background-color: #034078;
}

.fcc-btn-on:hover {
  background-color: #1282a2;
}

fcc-btn-off {
  background-color: #858585;
}

.fcc-btn-off:hover {
  background-color: #252524;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 70%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 450px) {
  table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 25%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
  }
}

th {
  padding: 12px;
  background-color: #0043af;
  color: white;
}

tr {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 12px;
}

tr:hover {
  background-color: #bcbcbc;
}

td {
  border: none;
  padding: 12px;
}

.sensor {
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 1px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.3.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<body>
  <h2>Configuration</h2>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="card-grid">
      <form action="/" method="POST">
        <div class="card">
          <p class="card-title">WIFI</p>
          <p>
            <label for="ssid">SSID</label><br>
            <input type="text" id="ssid" name="ssid" value="myssid"><br>
              <label for="password">Password</label><br>
              <input type="password" id="password" name="password" minlength="8" maxlength="63" >
              <i class="bi bi-eye-slash" id="togglePassword"></i>
          </p>
        </div>

      </form>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
i {
  margin-left: -60px;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
}
```